# Checking remote PowerShell session information from within a function

Tags: powershell, session

I've written a PS function to set a mailbox to a shared mailbox. The function works by calling a remote PS session to the exchange admin PS using

$session = New-PSSession -configurationName Microsoft.Exchange -connectionURI xxxx -Auth xxx
Import-PSSession $session

this all works fine.

But when i call the function from my leavers script it always tries to load the $session even if its already been done, this throws verious issues, but fundamentally the script works fine.

So i added a check to see if the session was already in place by using

If(($session.state -eq "closed") -or (!($session))){then load session}

but it seems to think the session doesn't exist and tries to re-import the session causing the errors. If i put a write-host $session before the IF statement it returns $null, so i don't understand why i get the error about the session already been in memory.

if i run the script outside of the function i get the expected behaviour of not loading the session if its already been loaded.

i could add a close session at the end of the function, but its not as efficient having to re-load it every time it runs.

this is the function

```
Function SetMailbox-ToShared {
#This function sets the mailbox to type shared
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $upn
    
)

#Get password details for on premises service account
# Application (client) ID, tenant Name and secret
$clientId = "xxx" #application ID
$tenantName = "xxx"
$clientSecret = "xxx"

$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://vault.azure.net/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

$secretURL = "https://xxx/secrets/xxx?api-version=2016-10-01"

$secretValue = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $secretURL).value

$exchUserName = "xxx"
$exchpwdTxt = "$secretValue" 
$exchangeConnectionURI = "http://xxx/PowerShell/"

  
If(($session.state -eq "Closed") -or (!($session))){
  $securePwd = $exchpwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString -asplaintext -force
  $credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $exchUserName, $securePwd
  $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $exchangeConnectionURI -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $credObject
  Import-PSSession $Session
}

Try{
  Set-RemoteMailbox $upn -type Shared
}
Catch{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error setting mailbox for $upn to type shared. The error was $_"
}

   
}
```

Which i then call from my main script using setmailbox-toshared -upn xxx.xxx@xxx.com

i hope i've explained that ok?

Comment: Can you show us how you invoke your remote function please?

Comment: i've updated the question with the function and how im calling it

Comment: This could be a [scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) issue. Inside the function, try to reference the `$Session` variable as `$script:session` or `$global:session`

Comment: i wondered if it might be along those lines, but because everything was running within that function i expected it to stay within it - will check and let you know

Comment: i think i may just have found the cause of this. If i run get-pssession it lists all the remote sessions, but hthey are with names such as WinRM467 and its not longer being stored in the variable - i guess because the $session variable isn't global - it looks like the remote session sits outside of the function

Comment: The remote session is established "globally", but the _variable_ named `session` stops existing as soon as the function returns - as @Theo mentions you can use `$script:session` or `$global:session` to store the session reference beyond the scope of the function